# Yii: prevent sensitive data from loading via relations

Tags: database, security, yii, relationship

For example I have a model called *Entity* and a model called *User*. Each entity *BELONGS_TO* a single user. Perfect case to establish a relationship.

Still user contains some sensitive data, like a password. How do I prevent those data to be loaded, when requesting entity-with-user?

*P.S.* I understand that its better to design your database schema separating auth data and publicly available data. E.g. store password in *User* model and username in *Profile* model. Still my question is how to maintain security in presented case.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this could be used:

```
public function relations()
{

    return array(
            'user' =>  array(self::BELONGS_TO,'User','id_field','select'=>'name,surname,otherfield1,field2'),
    );
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to restrict the fields generally in the User model, you could try using `defaultScope` combined with using [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/) to determine when ALL fields can be selected.

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    if ( $this->scenario != 'yourScenario' ) {
      return array(
          'select'=>"name,surname,otherfield1,field2",
      );
    } else {
      return array();
    }      
}
```

Comment: Might work, but it means each model having this relation is responsible for security issues. Is there a way to do it in User model. E.g. restrict loading password field, unless another model requests it explicitly?